# self.view?.presentScene: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, null, crash

I am trying to switch scenes but my app is crashing giving me this error:

```
crash
crash
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Here's my code for switching scenes:

```
func switchscenes() {

    if display >= 2 {
        Player.removeFromParent()
        PlayerRight.removeFromParent()
        PlayerLeft.removeFromParent()
        fireHair.removeFromParent()
        fireHairRight.removeFromParent()
        fireHairLeft.removeFromParent()
        imageRightView.removeFromSuperview()
        imageLeftView.removeFromSuperview()
                                    println("crash")
        var gameplayScene:SKScene = GamePlay(size: self.size)
                                    println("crash")
        self.view?.presentScene(gameplayScene)
                                    println("crash")
        display = 0

    }
}
```

And then in view did load:

```
timer5 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("switchscenes"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

It is printing crash twice but not a third time showing that

```
self.view?.presentScene(gameplayScene)
```

is the cause of the error. How can I fix this?

EDIT:

GamePlay.swift code:

```
import SpriteKit
import Foundation
import UIKit
import iAd

//Collisions
struct PhysicsCategory {
static let Enemy : UInt32 = 1
static let Player : UInt32 = 2
static let PlayerRight : UInt32 = 3
static let PlayerLeft : UInt32 = 4
static let SuperBlock : UInt32 = 5
}

var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)


var superblockRandomizer = NSTimeInterval()
var timer8 : NSTimer!
var playerVelocity :CGFloat!

class GamePlay: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var SuperBlock = SKShapeNode()



var redRandom : CGFloat = 1
var greenRandom : CGFloat = 1
var blueRandom : CGFloat = 1


//Highscore Variable
var Highscore = Int()

var fontsize : CGFloat = 20

//Score
var Score : Int = 0
var ScoreLabel = UILabel()

//Snow
var snow = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "SnowShower")

//Rain
var rain = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "RainShower")

//Fire Hair
var fireHair = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "FireHair")

//Fire Hair Right
var fireHairRight = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "FireHair")

//Fire Hair Left
var fireHairLeft = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "FireHair")

//Main Character
var Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mainPlayer.png")

//Right-far character
var PlayerRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mainPlayer.png")

//Left-far character
var PlayerLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mainPlayer.png")


//Holding vs Tapping Movement of Player
var isTouching = false

var touchXPosition:CGFloat = 0


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */


    playerVelocity = (size.width / 25)

    let controller = self.view?.window?.rootViewController as? GameViewController

    // Preload a new iAd
    interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
    interAd.delegate = controller

    adLoaded = false

    superblockRandomizer = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(5) + 5)

    let spawnBlock = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(spawnEnemies), SKAction.waitForDuration(0.3)])
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnBlock))

    let runScore = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(scoreCounter), SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1)])
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(runScore))

    let spawnSuperBlock = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(superblockRandomizer), SKAction.runBlock(spawnSuperBlocks)])
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnSuperBlock))

    snow.particleBirthRate = 15

    fireHair.particleBirthRate = 200

    fireHairRight.particleBirthRate = 200

    fireHairLeft.particleBirthRate = 200

    rain.particleBirthRate = 100

    //Highscore
    var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if (HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil) {
        Highscore = HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger
    }
    else {
        Highscore = 0
    }

    //Collisions/Physics
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    //Background Color
    scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    //Player coordinates
    Player.position.x = size.width * 0.5
    Player.position.y = size.height / 3

    //Setting Player Sizes
    Player.size.width = size.width * 0.11
    Player.size.height = size.width * 0.11
    PlayerRight.size.width = size.width * 0.11
    PlayerRight.size.height = size.width * 0.11
    PlayerLeft.size.width = size.width * 0.11
    PlayerLeft.size.height = size.width * 0.11

    //Setting hair position range
    fireHair.particlePositionRange = CGVector(dx: size.width * 0.11, dy: 0)
    fireHairRight.particlePositionRange = CGVector(dx: size.width * 0.11, dy: 0)
    fireHairLeft.particlePositionRange = CGVector(dx: size.width * 0.11, dy: 0)

    //Setting snow position range
    snow.particlePositionRange = CGVector(dx: size.width, dy: 0)

    //Initial position of player
    Player.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x, y: Player.position.y)
    //Initial position of far-right player
    PlayerRight.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x + size.width, y: Player.position.y)
    //Initial position of far-left player
    PlayerLeft.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x - size.width, y: Player.position.y)

    //Adding Physics/Collisions to Player
    Player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: Player.size)
    Player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    Player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy | PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock
    Player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    //Adding Physics/Collisions to PlayerRight
    PlayerRight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: PlayerRight.size)
    PlayerRight.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    PlayerRight.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.PlayerRight
    PlayerRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy | PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock
    PlayerRight.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    //Adding Physics/Collisions to PlayerLeft
    PlayerLeft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: PlayerRight.size)
    PlayerLeft.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    PlayerLeft.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.PlayerLeft
    PlayerLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy | PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock
    PlayerLeft.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    //Making Players visible
    self.addChild(Player)
    self.addChild(PlayerRight)
    self.addChild(PlayerLeft)
    self.addChild(fireHair)
    self.addChild(fireHairRight)
    self.addChild(fireHairLeft)

    if size.height <= 569 {
        fontsize = 20
    }
    else if size.height >= 569 {

        fontsize = 25
    }

    //Making Score Visible
    ScoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
    ScoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: fontsize*5, height: fontsize))
    ScoreLabel.font = UIFont(name: ScoreLabel.font.fontName, size: fontsize)
    ScoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view?.addSubview(ScoreLabel)
}

func scoreCounter() {
    //Setting score
    Score += 1
    ScoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
}


func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    //Checking for Player to enemy collisions
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Player)){
        CollisionWithEnemy(firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode, Player: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) {
        CollisionWithEnemy2(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Enemy: secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)
    }
    //Checking for PlayerRight to enemy collisions
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerRight)){
        CollisionWithEnemy(firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode, Player: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerRight) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) {
        CollisionWithEnemy2(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Enemy: secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)
    }
    //Checking for PlayerLeft to enemy collisions
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerLeft)){
        CollisionWithEnemy(firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode, Player: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerLeft) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) {
        CollisionWithEnemy2(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Enemy: secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)
    }

    if SuperBlock.position.y > size.height / 2 {
    //Checking for enemy to enemy collisions
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy)){
        SuperBlockWithEnemy(firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode, Enemy: secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)

    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock) {
        SuperBlockWithEnemy2(firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode, SuperBlock: secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)
    }
    }

    //Checking for Player to superblock collisions
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Player)){
        CollisionWithSuper(firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode, Player: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock) {
        CollisionWithSuper2(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, SuperBlock: secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)
    }

    //Checking for PlayerRight to superblock collisions
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerRight)){
        CollisionWithSuper(firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode, Player: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerRight) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock) {
        CollisionWithSuper2(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, SuperBlock: secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)
    }

    //Checking for PlayerLeft to superblock collisions
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerLeft)){
        CollisionWithSuper(firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode, Player: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerLeft) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock) {
        CollisionWithSuper2(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, SuperBlock: secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)
    }

}

func CollisionWithEnemy(Enemy: SKShapeNode, Player: SKSpriteNode) {

    //Highscore
    var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()


    if (Score > Highscore) {
        var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        HighscoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Highscore")
    }

    var gameOver:SKScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
    ScoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    Player.removeFromParent()

    self.view?.presentScene(gameOver, transition: transition)



}

func CollisionWithEnemy2(Player: SKSpriteNode, Enemy: SKShapeNode) {

    //Highscore
    var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()

    if (Score > Highscore) {
        var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        HighscoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Highscore")
    }

    var gameOver:SKScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
    ScoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    Player.removeFromParent()




    self.view?.presentScene(gameOver, transition: transition)



}

func SuperBlockWithEnemy(SuperBlock: SKShapeNode, Enemy: SKShapeNode) {

    Enemy.removeFromParent()
}

func SuperBlockWithEnemy2(Enemy: SKShapeNode, SuperBlock: SKShapeNode) {

    Enemy.removeFromParent()
}

func CollisionWithSuper(SuperBlock: SKShapeNode, Player: SKSpriteNode) {

    //Highscore
    var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()


    if (Score > Highscore) {
        var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        HighscoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Highscore")
    }

    var gameOver:SKScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
    ScoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    Player.removeFromParent()
    self.view?.presentScene(gameOver, transition: transition)


}

func CollisionWithSuper2(Player: SKSpriteNode, SuperBlock: SKShapeNode) {
    //Highscore
    var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()

    if (Score > Highscore) {
        var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        HighscoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Highscore")
    }

    var gameOver:SKScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
    ScoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    Player.removeFromParent()
    self.view?.presentScene(gameOver, transition: transition)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    isTouching = true

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        touchXPosition = location.x

    }

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    isTouching = false
}

func spawnSuperBlocks() {

    superblockRandomizer = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(5) + 5)


    //Randomizing width of blocks
    var blockWidth = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.width / 3)) + UInt32(size.width / 3))

    //Min and Max position of blocks
    var minPosition : UInt32 = UInt32(blockWidth / 2)
    var maxPosition : UInt32 = UInt32(size.width - CGFloat(blockWidth / 2))

    //Randomizing Block Position
    var blockXPosition = arc4random_uniform(maxPosition - minPosition) + minPosition

    //Making Blocks
    SuperBlock = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: blockWidth, height: Int(size.height / 12)))
    SuperBlock.position = CGPointMake (CGFloat(blockXPosition),  CGFloat(size.height+size.height / 5))

    //Coloring Blocks
    redRandom = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200) + 56)
    greenRandom = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200) + 56)
    blueRandom = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200) + 56)


    SuperBlock.fillColor = SKColor(red: redRandom / 255, green: greenRandom / 255, blue: blueRandom / 255, alpha: 1)
    SuperBlock.lineWidth = 0

    //Moving Blocks
    let action = SKAction.moveToY(-50, duration: 1)

    //Removing blocks once off screen
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    //Running the above actions
    SuperBlock.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))


    //Physics/Collisions
    SuperBlock.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize (width: blockWidth, height: 50))
    SuperBlock.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.SuperBlock
    SuperBlock.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    SuperBlock.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    SuperBlock.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    //Adding enemy to scene
    self.addChild(SuperBlock)
}

func spawnEnemies() {

    //Randomizing width of blocks
    var blockWidth = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.width / 3)) + UInt32(size.width / 4))

    //Min and Max position of blocks
    var minPosition : UInt32 = UInt32(blockWidth / 2)
    var maxPosition : UInt32 = UInt32(size.width - CGFloat(blockWidth / 2))

    //Randomizing Block Position
    var blockXPosition = arc4random_uniform(maxPosition - minPosition) + minPosition


    var sideblockPositionMin = UInt32(blockWidth / 2)

    var sideblockPositionMax = UInt32(size.width - CGFloat(blockWidth / 2))


    var randomizer2 = arc4random_uniform(10)

    if randomizer2 == 5 {
        blockXPosition = sideblockPositionMin
    }
    else if randomizer2 == 7 {
        blockXPosition = sideblockPositionMax
    }
    else {

    }

    //Making Blocks
    var Enemy = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: blockWidth, height: Int(size.height / 100)))
    Enemy.position = CGPointMake (CGFloat(blockXPosition),  CGFloat(size.height+size.height / 12))

    //Coloring Blocks
    Enemy.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    //Moving Blocks
    let action = SKAction.moveToY(-50, duration: 1.5)

    //Removing blocks once off screen
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    //Running the above actions
    Enemy.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

    //Physics/Collisions
    Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize (width: blockWidth, height: 1))
    Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    Enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    //Adding enemy to scene
    self.addChild(Enemy)

}

func spawn() {

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    Player.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x, y: Player.position.y)

    PlayerRight.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x + size.width, y: Player.position.y)

    PlayerLeft.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x - size.width, y: Player.position.y)

    fireHair.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x, y: Player.position.y - Player.size.height / 1.5)

    fireHairRight.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x + size.width, y: Player.position.y - Player.size.height / 1.5)

    fireHairLeft.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x - size.width, y: Player.position.y - Player.size.height / 1.5)

    if isTouching {
        if touchXPosition > self.size.width / 2 {
            // move character to the right.
            Player.position.x += playerVelocity

        }
        if touchXPosition < self.size.width / 2 {
            // move character to the left.
            Player.position.x -= playerVelocity

        }
    }

    if Player.position.x < 0 {
        Player.position.x = Player.position.x + size.width
        PlayerRight.position.x = Player.position.x + size.width
        PlayerLeft.position.x = Player.position.x - size.width
    }
    if Player.position.x > size.width {
        Player.position.x = Player.position.x - size.width
        PlayerRight.position.x = Player.position.x + size.width
        PlayerLeft.position.x = Player.position.x - size.width
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Still can't figure this out

Comment: Added a bounty, cant figure this out and my app was rejected because of this issue.

Comment: Can you add GamePlay.swift. code. Can not see any problem here.

Comment: Added for you Cagatay.

Comment: Have you tried to check `self.view?.presentScene(gameplayScene)` against `nil`?

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with the Highscore in gameplay.swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out after days. I wanted to do a cool rain/snow affect early on in development, but I eventually decided against it. Turns out I still had a few lines of code that related to the Rain and Snow but they were loading a nil SKEmitterNode(file named:)that I had deleted.

Comment: In the future, this type of problem is quite easily solved by a) looking at the stack backtrace to find where the problem occurs, and failing that b) examining the force unwraps in your code - one of them is the culprit.